# Handle TimeOut Service Bus Processor

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am currently writing azure service bus processor to process message from queue. If my process takes a long time (more than lock duration of message) than shouln't it timeout before it is available for another processor.

e.g. I have below code while doing ProcessMessageAsync handler and I have lock duration of 30 seconds.

```
          Console.WriteLine($"Message Recevied {args.Message.SequenceNumber}");

           await Task.Delay(5 * 10000);
```

I have also method attached to ProcessErrorAsync which I would expect that will handle exceptions. I see when message is not finished it gets available to other processor which case same message is now executing by multiple process. Is there a way that this can be avoided. We basically want if a process timesout than put the message with a delay to Service Bus.

Answer (score 0):

There is. You can extend the maximum default lock duration by specifying message processor setting [`MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessoroptions.maxautolockrenewalduration?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusprocessoroptions-maxautolockrenewalduration), defining the maximum possible processing time for a message.

Comment: Thanks @sean, around Topic Subscription. As we can have multiple subscribers for a topic and if there is an error happened during message processing at subscription level than if we have to retry(not client side) which means a subscriber wants to try message at later time and to do that we need to delay message which would create clone message and put back to SB but this case the new clone message can be received by another subscriber.  Some how the overall retry pattern in Service bus is making complex where a consumer wants to retry message later. Is filter only the option to handle.

Comment: This is a whole different topic  There's nothing special about topic/subscription. It's the same pattern: competing consumers. Retries will happen if a message lock is lost or a client is disconnected. The design of the system should always account for that.

Comment: I think the one issue with Service bus is that if we have to retry message after 2 hours than we need to create new message which makes system very complex as we need to complete the original message and create new message which would eventually can fill your topic or queue, more in topic.

Comment: If you have to do something based on time, schedule your message. If you need to control when a message is processed based on a criteria, defer it. I'm still getting a vibe there's something architecturally off. Either ASB not the service you need or how it's utilized is not quite right. Either way, I'm wondering way off the scope of the original question here 

Comment: Ok sure thanks will post to a new question if needed. thanks for your help :)